Excel crashes when row in listbox is selected
Suddenly, my Excel file crashes when I select a listbox row in my userform. I'm able to search the listbox and it works fine and the file doesn't crash. It's only when I execute the click event below that Excel crashes. I'm still learning VBA - so is there a method for finding the cause? I tried using a breakpoint, but I didn't learn anything from it.
I would greatly appreciate your help.
UPDATE: The crashing occurs at line:
.txtPODate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 23)
Right before the crash, I worked on the second block of code. Can you see anything suspicious there?
Private Sub lstMaster_Click() 'Click on row in listbox to select record
    With Me.lstMaster
    End With
    With Me
        .txtPrefix.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 0)
        .cboOrderType.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 1)
        .cboStatus.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 2)
        .txtSuffix.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 3)
        .txtShopOrdNum.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 4)
        .txtEmailSubLine.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 5)
        .txtNotes.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 6)
        .cboStage.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 7)
        .txtResponsible.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 8)
        .txtStartDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 9)
        .txtEndDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 10)
        .txtDays.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 11)
        .cboReason.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 12)
        .txtProposal.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 13)
        .cboSalesPer.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 14)
        .txtPrimSales.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 15)
        .txtPropDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 16)
        .txtLT.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 17)
        .txtPromDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 18)
        .txtExpDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 19)
        .txtCost.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 20)
        .txtMargin.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 21)
        .txtPO.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 22)
        .txtPODate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 23)
        .txtPORecDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 24)
        .txtPOAmt.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 25)
        .cboTerms.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 26)
        .txtE10Terms.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 27)
        .cboShipVia.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 28)
        .cboShipType.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 29)
        .cboShipChrgs.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 30)
        .txtShipInst.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 31)
        .txtSO.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 32)
        .txtQuote.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 33)
        .txtPM.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 34)
        .txtEE.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 35)
        .txtSys.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 36)
        .cboSCodeDes.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 37)
        .txtSCode.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 38)
        .txtBMTH.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 39)
        .txtTransOrdNum.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 40)
        .txtInstlDays.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 41)
        .txtStrtUpDays.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 42)
        .txtTrngDaysOn.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 43)
        .txtTrngDaysTol.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 44)
        .txtVndrSrvDays.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 45)
        .txtSrvTech.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 46)
        .txtStndHrs12.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 47)
        .txtStndHrs3.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 48)
        .txtSatSunHol.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 49)
        .txtAddOvrTm.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 50)
        .txtTrvlLess.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 51)
        .txtTrvlMore.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 52)
        .txtAirfare.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 53)
        .txtHotel.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 54)
        .txtCarRntl.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 55)
        .txtMeals.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 56)
        .txtMileage.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 57)
        .txtParking.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 58)
        .txtSrvPrts1.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 59)
        .txtSrvPrts2.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 60)
        .txtBkgFees.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 61)
        .txtSummary.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 62)
        .txtSrvTtl.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 63)
        .cboSrvGrp.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 64)
        .txtQuoteApproved.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 65)
        .txtConPO.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 66)
        .txtE10.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 67)
        .txtReqApp.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 68)
        .txtPMAssign.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 69)
        .txtSOPM.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 70)
        .txtApproved.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 71)
        .txtSOCust.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 72)
        .txtSOE10.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 73)
        .txtCurPromDate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 74)
        .cboRecRev.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 75)
        .txtShipReq.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 76)
        .txtShipped.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 77)
        .txtBOL.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 78)
        .txtLines.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 79)
        .txtReqInvDep.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 80)
        .txtInvDep.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 81)
        .txtInvDepPaid.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 82)
        .txtReqInvPreShip.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 83)
        .txtInvPreShip.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 84)
        .txtInvPreShipPaid.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 85)
        .txtReqInvFinal.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 86)
        .txtInvFinal.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 87)
        .txtInvFinalPaid.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 88)
        .txtRecogApp.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 89)
        .txtRecogNum.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 90)
        .txtRecogMktg.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 91)
        .txtRecogSch.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 92)
        .txtRecogPub.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 93)
        .txtName.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 94)
        .txtNickname.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 95)
        .txtDiamond.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 96)
        .txtCustID.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 97)
        .txtBT.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 98)
        .txtBTAddr1.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 99)
        .txtBTAddr2.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 100)
        .txtBTCity.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 101)
        .txtBTState.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 102)
        .txtBTZip.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 103)
        .txtBTCntry.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 104)
        .cboTE.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 105)
        .txtCon1.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 106)
        .txtEmail1.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 107)
        .txtCon2.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 108)
        .txtEmail2.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 109)
        .txtSTName.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 110)
        .txtSTID.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 111)
        .txtSTNum.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 112)
        .txtSTAddr1.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 113)
        .txtSTAddr2.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 114)
        .txtSTCity.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 115)
        .txtSTState.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 116)
        .txtSTZip.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 117)
        .txtSTCntry.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 118)
        .txtEUName.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 119)
        .txtEUNickname.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 120)
        .txtEUID.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 121)
        .txtTimestamp.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 122)
    End With
    cmbNew.Enabled = True 'v13
    cmbSave.Enabled = True 'v13
    cmbDelete.Enabled = True 'v13
End Sub 'lstMaster_Click()

Private Sub txtPODate_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    With txtPODate
        If IsDate(.Text) Then
            .BackColor = &HFFC0C0    'purple
            .Text = CDate(.Text)
        ElseIf .Text > "" Then
            .BackColor = vbYellow
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date."
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf .Text = "" Then
            .BackColor = &HFFC0C0    'purple
        End If
    End With
End Sub  'txtPODate_BeforeUpdate 'format date


Have you tried stepping through the code?

Yes, I go to Debug > Step Into. It starts at Private Sub Userform_Initialize. I move my cursor to the code above, then select Run To Cursor. The userform opens. I click on one of the rows of the listbox and it crashes.

Put a stop point on the first line of the lsMaster_Click sub, then step through the code line by line after you've clicked on a listbox

Ok, so I found the 'bad' line: .txtPODate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 23). So I assume I use the same technique on code that includes txtPODate?

Not an answer to your problem, but you could simplify your code (reduce bulk) by creating a function which returns a row from your list box as an array.  Eg: Dim arr: arr = ListRow(Me.lstMaster)   Then you can write (eg) .txtPrefix.Value = arr(0)

And Yes - step through txtPODate_BeforeUpdate and see if you can figure out which specific line there is the problem.

I agree with you on 'bulk'. I want to tackle that once I get this crashing fixed. I'm stuck. I set a breakpoint at the 'bad' line: .txtPODate.Value = .lstMaster.List(lstMaster.ListIndex, 23) AND on the first line of txtPODate_BeforeUpdate. When the 'bad' line is highlighted, I click on F8 and the file crashes. I'm not able to 'analyze' the second procedure.

So, I deactivated the txtPODate_BeforeUpdate procedure and when I click on the listbox, it still crashes. So, it doesn't appear that txtPODate_BeforeUpdate is the culprit.

Seems like you have quite a complex/large form, so it might be difficult for someone here to replicate the problem unless you're able to share the file...

You're correct, Tim. It's a whopper. I always appreciate your insight!

I think you already have my contact info, so if you're able to send it I will try to take a look...

Yes, I think your information is on my home PC. Thank you!

@TimWilliams I believe I lost your information. Ever since posting this issue, I've been trying to resolve it myself to no avail. Would you please resend your info?

I sent a mail to your gmail address.

I just replied to your email. Thank you!
